# Is it possible to get back user_id programmatically when user browse a site?

Tags: google-analytics, google-datalayer, gtag.js

I use gtag manager to push unique user_id from my site to ga. I wanna get it back like client_id when a user browse my site.

I definitely know that gtag does not allow to do that. also there is a dataLayer which can be queried like that
`google_tag_manager['<container-id>'].dataLayer.get('gtm.start')` but I've not found a solution to get user_id back.

Is it possible somehow to get back this user_id or it works only in one way to enrich ga?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the real time, it works one way only. It's your responsibility to save whatever you need appropriately.

If it's shifted in time sufficiently (about 2 days shift), you theoretically could use the [Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) or a BQ export to pull it by something like GA client id. But that's way too cumbersome. Much easier to preserve the user id in the normal way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Audience List methods](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/audience-list-basics) in the GA4 Data API to get the Client/Device IDs & User IDs of users in your audiences. Each row of the response represents a user can contain their associated Client/Device IDs & User ID.